# Can't connect to port 22, Connection timed out

Tags: ssh

I just recently got into whatever you might call this stuff. I was just trying to send a java file over to the computer I ssh to. But when I went to do it, I just get told
sh: connect to host port 22: Connection timed out
lost connection

If possible I would like it explained very simply because of how new I am to this kind of stuff.

Comment: Being new to this stuff, you will benefit from reading the tutorial. Specifically, how to ask a good question (hint: this one *isn't* good). https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It sounds like the SSH server may not be running on the target machine. But this is a little off-topic for StackOverflow. What about posting it on https://SuperUser.com/?

Answer (score -1):

**SSH to remote host(VM Ubuntu) from VS code terminal**

Install VS Code with Remote Development extension pack.

Install Virtual machine (Virtual box) and Ubuntu running on it.

Check Ubuntu-Network-Settings-IPv4 address (10.0.2.15-default for VM).

Go to your virtual box Settings-Network-NAT Adapter (double-check).

Go to your virtual box Settings-Network-In Advanced-Port Forwarding.

Add this as given below and click ok and hereafter consider 127.0.1.1 for ssh.

[portforwardinginVM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FltV3.jpg)

View the status and disable firewall settings in Ubuntu VM (ufw command).

In VS Code, View-Command Palette- Add new SSH host .

Add ssh username@127.0.1.1 and enter.

Or go to the terminal window (eg. Powershell) and type ssh username@127.0.1.1, it will ask if you want to update to host lists permanently, asking like yes/no and also your Ubuntu password to confirm.

Now try to connect to the host using  username@127.0.1.1 and selecting OS like Ubuntu, then type the Ubuntu password.

That's it you are logged in to your virtual machine and can access files now from your local machine.

Comment: Please share more details. Why do you need to add a virtual machine to connect to another machine?

Comment: I am clearly telling a way to connect local computer to another machine (for eg. virtual machine) via ssh. The case, where two devices needs to be communicated.

Comment: And how could this help to connect two real computers? Why should anybody configure VirtualBox for this?